# Spring JpaRepository findAll method execution returns empty/no data silently

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my production code I was using spring JPARepository.findAll method, we suspect that for one of its execution it returned an empty list (though db table is having the data )instead of throwing an exception which broken the downstream code. We did not have the debug logs to see what was being actual returned. There is not much documentation available of findAll. Is there any possibility that findAll could return empty data ( though data was present in the data base)?

Comment: Could you please share your sample code ?

Comment: `findAll` will return an empty list if it doesn't retrieve any data, it will not throw an exception. Why should it as a collection can be empty. If there is a connection error or something like that the exception will be propagated.

Comment: Posting your code may lead to more helpful responses. Are you using @Transactional? Is your repo pulling from more than one table? If so, what are the entity relationships (e.g., @ManyToOne)? Are you specifying an explicit FetchType?

Answer (score 0):

Just return an empty list from your catch block:

```
catch (Exception e){
  Log.error(e);
  return new ArrayList<POJO>();
}
```

Comment: Rephrased my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where **repository.findById(id)** would return a result and **repository.findAll()** would return empty.
The issue was I had wrapped the caller method with **@Transactional(readOnly = true)**, where the method would write and then read all records:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Object> writeThenReadAll(...){
       repository.save(...);
       ...
       Object byId = repository.findById(1L).get(); //return record
       List<Object> all = repository.findAll(); //empty List
       return all;
    }
```

changing **@Transactional(readOnly = true)** to @**Transactional(readOnly = false)** fixed the issue.

Comment: I am using  @Transactional which is read/write by default.

Answer (score 0):

I Had a same problem while working with JPARepository, My problem goes off by
using the @Autowired annotations inside controller from where you are calling this method.